# JComponents not displaying in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Here is the a snippet of code I have in my main class:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

GPComponent gp = new GPComponent(n, k);
GPinfinityComponent gpi = new GPinfinityComponent(n, k);

panel.add(gp);
panel.add(gpi);

frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // just to be clear
frame.setVisible(true);
final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
frame.setTitle("GP("+n+", "+k+")");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The details of GPComponent and GPinfinityComponent are unecessary... they extend JComponent and when I put them into the frame individually (without using a panel) they work fine. However, I wanted to display one over the other using a JPanel so I wouldn't have to programs running to complete the same task. Each of the JComponents will be updated individually later using custom methods... again this all works until I try to combine them. Essentially, my question is am I setting up adding JComponents to the JPanel and then that to the JFrame correctly? I just want my components to display...

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might want to try adding the panel to the frame's `contentPanel` instead of to the frame directly (although I haven't actually tested this, so I am unsure if it will fix your problem)

Comment: It should't matter: `JFrame#add()` forwards to the content pane. Why not `CardLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further eviden, it's probable that your two custom components do not override the `getPreferredSize` method (or fail to use an appropriate layout manager, which generates this value), this would mean that the `FlowLayout`, which is the default layout manager for `JPanel`, they are automatically been size to `0x0`

Another test would be to call `pack` on the frame, which will attempt to pack the frame to its contents preferred size

Comment: The layout manager is probably the culprit given that the default layout for the `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout` vs. `FlowLayout` for the `JPanel`. However, if you're looking to use one of these components as a mask to block input into the frame while a task is running, then I'd recommend looking at using the glass pane component of the JFrame instead especially if you have many controls in your JFrame.

Comment: What type of code would I in the body of getPreferredSize method if I wanted to override it? The only method my components have overridden is the paintComponent method.

Comment: @jgibson Or a JLayeredPane or an OverlayLayout, depending on what is required

Comment: @user2154420 you would return the "preferred" size of your component would like, assuming all other factors are equal...

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks a lot! One last quick question: Is there a way to make it so one component in the panel is "fixed", or so one component remains "centered" within its section as the frame changes size, or say a scrollbar moves the fram horizontally? Currently, the first component remains fixed and the other component moves (and can move on top of the other) as the size of the window changes.

Comment: You might be able to do it with GridBagLayout